# Error "invalid json" in inserting document in Couchdb through command line

Tags: json, couchdb

I am  getting any "error: bad request,invalid json" while running

```
curl  -X PUT "http://localhost:5984/test" -d '{"valid":"json"}'
```

what to do for inserting document in database test through command line???

Answer (score 1):

When doing a `PUT` the `_id` of the document should be provided in the URL. So e.g.:

```
curl  -X PUT "http://localhost:5984/test/my-id" -d '{"valid":"json"}'
```

If you want Couch to generate the id, use a `POST` instead.

Comment: I tried it too by providing the id field too but error remains same...invalid json..

Comment: Did U provide the Id in the URL or in the document?

Comment: I provided the id in the url which i got after executing curl -X get "http://localhost:5984/_uuids"

Comment: Just tried the same and then invoked the command I wrote above replacing `my-id` with the UUID. Worked! Have you tried other tool? E.g. Postman. Does `POST` work, where no `_id` is specified. Not in URL and not in the document.

Comment: I have tried this command in command line...i too have tried replacing my_id with uuid...Actually commands(which i have posted above and one other command in which I tried to ran view) are not working from command line....

Comment: Have you tried escaping the JSON? E.g. '{\"valid\":\"json\"}'

Comment: Did U ever try something else, like Postman, to do the request?